# Feedback on Crystal layout & signal routing for SPI /CAN

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, spi, layout, crystal

Crystal:NX5032GA 16Mhz

i havnt had the experience in laying out crystals, im personally using https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00221665-oscillator-design-guide-for-stm8afals-stm32-mcus-and-mpus-stmicroelectronics.pdf as a reference and just want to double check if i've misunderstood something along the line.
main things i've taken away

1. a guard ring is required around the clock
2. seperate GND plane under the clock
3. Short distance from the MCU

With regards to the SPI line, its speed is at 4Mhz and i've set the MISO MOSI to be the same length.
is it important to have them all the same length ?

and with my CAN lines, i've used Saturn PCB toolkit to set the differential rules.

[image: Board Design]

Updated board::
[image]

Comment: ok, do you have a reference document, rule set or advice to follow when laying crystals out ?
for example, no ground plane under the clock ect ect

Comment: I decided to remove what I said. None of it necessarily hurts things (except for maybe the parasitic capacitance from the ground plane throwing the capacitances off by too much, but this can be compensated for by using smaller caps). It just might not be needed.

Comment: The crystal layout should work just fine. It looks like one of those textbook examples and is most likely over-engineeded for what you need. SPI MISO and MOSI don't need to be of same length, they are driven with completely different chips so they won't have equal timing in any way. Are those CAN wires the logic level CAN and the PHY is external? Or are those CAN wires the bus and PHY is internal? You might want to open up this a little. Which MCU, which SPI device, how the CAN works?

Comment: oh ok, i was under the impression that all the signal lines for SPI were to be of similiar length.

im using a STM ic so the can is bxcan. might be considering one of the spc or STM8 cpu which then changes it to  NXP can.  the can wires are internal so to a nxp tranceiver  which then are routed differentially to the output connection

Comment: i've also since updated it and make more space between the spi and can bus

Comment: technically MOSI and MISO should both be length matched with the SCK line, since thats what matters for both of them (and therefore they should be length matched with each other), but I can't imagine it makes any difference at 4Mhz unless its like literally meters of difference (and then you'd have a host of other problems)

Comment: The CAN RX and TX wires (the wires between the CAN transceiver and the MCU) do not necessarily have to have the same length because they are not differential. Having the CAN and SPI wires distant is good as there's a risk (though not significant) of crosstalk.

Comment: @DKNguyen I had come to some information that having the GND signal on the top layer under the clock is bad practice, is that true ?

Comment: @Lolcatsnin I don't know if it's bad, but I do know that if you're not paying attention it could cause your oscillator to stop working with your calculated capacitance values due to the additional parasitic capacitance.